# Import .cer into java keystore as "Trusted Certificate" and "Secure Site"

Tags: java, security, certificate

I try to import two .cert files into the java keystore.
One as "Trusted Certificate" and one as "Secure Site".

But they always get into "Secure Site CA".

What am I doing wrong?

This is my script:

```
C:
cd %programfiles%\java\jre6
.\bin\keytool.exe -importcert -alias zert1 -file D:\Certs\cert.cer -trustcacerts -keystore ./lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt
```

Comment: thats the alias for the certificate isn't it?
I just filled it up with zert1 ;-)

Comment: So what is `Trusted Certificate` and `Secure Site CA` you mention in OP?